# Bootstrap progress bar colors using angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i would like to know how can we make a `progress bar` change its color as the percentage value increases.

I want the progress bar to show a red(danger) until 33%. Then turn blue upto 66% and then turn green until 100%. Can this be done using `angular js`?

Comment: show some code! what did you try? what isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-class`.

[ui.bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has a good example of this for its rating control, using this technique:

```
ng-class="{'label-warning': percent<33, 'label-info': percent>=33 && percent<66, 'label-success': percent>=66}"
```

This works for progress bars as well.  You just need to define percent somewhere.
http://plnkr.co/iBliMPYnWbsJJCtzqWTu

Update:
Here are classes intended for bootstrap progress bars:

```
ng-class="{'progress-bar-danger': percent<33, 'progress-bar-info': percent>=33 && percent<66, 'progress-bar-success': percent>=66}"
```

Comment: haha that was clever to use that code. But the colors are not changing

Comment: Try the plunk now.  Maybe progress bar need progress bar classes only?

Comment: Hi i would like some help with this question. Could you help? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161742/angular-panel-replace-with-a-click-event/23162131?noredirect=1#23162131

Comment: Sure, i'll look at it tonight.

Comment: Hi can you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614387/angular-app-reading-from-a-nested-json-structure?noredirect=1#comment36253895_23614387

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use [angular-ui bootstrap's](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) `<progressbar>` directive.
The colors that you suggest for the percentages exists in their collection of colors to be assigned as types in a specific state of the progress that you define. These state definitions such as the change in color from a specific value percentage can be manipulated in your controllers. Simply follow the angular-ui implementation with their `<progressbar>` directive.

Comment: very nice.  i guess you can use `type` if you want controller to manage it, instead of `ng-class`.