# Angular panel replace with a click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following angular app with bootstrap: Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xkqITV8iFgCkDoxKlPN)

```
<div class="panel col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2">
            <div class="" id="menu">

                <div ng-controller="mylistcontroller" class="" id="menu">               
                <br/>
                <h4><font color=#636363>My Academic Programs</font><button id="tooltip1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Add a Program"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right"></span></button></h4>

                <div ng-repeat="prog in programs" class="list-group">

                    <a ng-repeat="list in prog.programstaken" href="#" class="list-group-item">

            {{list.program}}<span class="badge badge-info pull-right">{{list.completed}} / {{list.required}}</span>
            <progressbar class="progress-striped active" max="list.required" value="list.completed" type="{{getProgressType(list)}}">{{getPercentage(list)}}%</progressbar>

                  </a>              
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

When i click on the **+** button next to the **My Academic Programs**, i would like the app to replace the panel next to it that says `Tier 1-..` with a new panel which would have a dropdown of a list of courses from the json mentioned in the `programlist` in **app.js**. How do i approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the plus icon, set a variable that will control which panel is visible:

```
ng-click="display.addprogram = true"
```

Then use `ng-show` to toggle visibility of the `Tier 1-..` panel:

```
<div ng-show="!display.addprogram" ...> ...
```

Create another panel to hold the dropdown, and use `ng-show` again but with the opposite condition:

```
<div ng-show="display.addprogram" ...> ...
```

Then create the dropdown inside this panel.  Here is an example that does nothing more than toggle the visibility of the two panels.  You will probably create a function that actually does something with the selection, and then toggles the visibility.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="p in programs[0].programlist">
      <a ng-click="display.addprogram = false">{{p.program}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/gcnuuMUct5ghOkaIX6cF?p=preview

Note - I consolidated two controllers into one, so that both would have easy access to the `display.addprogram` variable.

Comment: wow!  awesome. So do i do a similar thing to get back the old panel when i click on the AS.SCIENCE in the list?

Comment: oh, i see what you mean.  yeah just add `ng-click="display.addprogram = false"` to the anchor tag.  i just added this to the plunker.

Comment: hi one last question, after selecting a program from the dropdown, how do we make it appear in the left side list(below the 'My Academic Programs'? I will post this as a separate question if you like.

Comment: Here is the question :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190745/angular-add-to-list-from-a-panel-add

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach it. A simple solution is to use the `ng-show` or `ng-if` directives on both of the HTML elements you are manipulating. You can have ng-click change a property on the $scope that `ng-show` / `ng-if` is bound to, and evaluates to true or false.