# Angular add to list from a panel add

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following angularjs app: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcnuuMUct5ghOkaIX6cF?p=preview)

When the **+** next to the `My academic course` is clicked, it opens a new panel to get a list of courses to select from. I would like to add a functionality to save the course clicked from the dropdown into the list of courses on the left of the page. How do i approach this?

Comment: to answer this question, I need to study your application as if I were developing with you. I do not have time to do it. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function to your scope to add the course:

```
$scope.addProgram = function(program) {
  $scope.programs[0].programstaken.push(program);
  $scope.display.addprogram = false;
}
```

Then, pass the program object created by `ng-repeat` to the `addProgram` function:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="p in programs[0].programlist">
      <a ng-click="addProgram(p)">{{p.program}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1TGsgcHafJd4tisuM8Wo?p=preview

Note that `display.addprogram = false` was moved from `ng-click` to inside the function for clarity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200584/angular-error-in-loading-correct-children