# Angular error in loading correct children

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular app:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGP1jKsWl6g6V6REeTRu?p=preview)

When the + next to the `My academic course` is clicked, it opens a new panel to get a list of courses to select from. Here when we click '`Academic`' it shows a new panel with all its children. But when i click `Associate in Applied Sciences Degree` it still shows me the same children? Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Comment: I think its because of this line `<li ng-repeat="p in programs[0].programlist[0].children" ... `. `programlist[0]`'s index should change on each iteration.

Comment: yeah even i thought the same. I was trying to play around with that line of code but it was not giving me the correct result anytime. Can you try getting it?

Comment: Perhaps something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/TwA162wUTVtb7OGtQdXa?p=preview

Comment: Hi that looks great? is it similar even for the subchildren? please post your answer so i can accept it :-)

Comment: subchildren? I didn't get your question..

Comment: yeah there is also a 'subchildren' category within the 'children' in the json. Even those are always getting the same data when we click on one of the 'children' in the panel.

Comment: yes, its the same issue. you're referencing the same object for every subchildren.. that's why you don't see proper data.

Comment: can you tell me what i am missing? i did a similar approach as yours for the subchildren http://plnkr.co/edit/Le2lXvMOxsbfuZtiVP4r?p=preview

Comment: i created a new clickhandler2 function for it but there is some error.  Can you help me rectify it?

Comment: Checkout the edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the best solution but here is the link to [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TwA162wUTVtb7OGtQdXa?p=preview).

**EDIT**: For subchildren: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Apc6hyHzAEFG6jMbDdAM?p=preview) ([from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200584/angular-error-in-loading-correct-children?noredirect=1#comment35499267_23200584)). This still has quite a few bugs (like: try clicking both checkboxes :D)

Here are my additions:
**Controller:**

```
$scope.clickHandler = function (index) {
    $scope.currentProgram = $scope.programs[0].programlist[index];
};
```

**View:**

```
 <li ng-repeat="p in programs[0].programlist" data-spy="scroll" >
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="display.addcourse = !display.addcourse; clickHandler($index)" value=""/>{{p.program}}
  </li>

  ...

    <div ng-show="display.addcourse" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <ul class="list-group" role="menu">
                <li ng-repeat="p in currentProgram.children" data-spy="scroll" class="list-group-item">
                    <a ng-click="display.addcoursedescription = true" >{{p.course}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```