# Angular app reading from a nested json structure

Tags: json, angularjs

I have an angular app which reads from a json that looks like the following:

```
[{
        "category": {
            "id": 40, 
            "name": "Category 1", 
            "parent": {
                "id": 38, 
                "name": "Parent Category 1", 
                "parent": {
                    "id": 23, 
                    "name": "Parent name", 
                    "level": 1
                }, 
                "level": 2
            }, 
            "level": 3
        }, 
        "subcategory": {
            "course_name": "Category Name 1", 
            "title": "Category Title", 
        }
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "id": 40, 
            "name": "Category 1", 
            "parent": {
                "id": 38, 
                "name": "Parent Category 1", 
                "parent": {
                    "id": 23, 
                    "name": "Parent name", 
                    "level": 1
                }, 
                "level": 2
            }, 
            "level": 3
        }, 
        "subcategory": {
            "course_name": "Category Name 2", 
            "title": "Category Title", 
        }
    },
    {
    "category": {
        "id": 40, 
        "name": "Category 1", 
        "parent": {
            "id": 39, 
            "name": "Parent Category 2", 
            "parent": {
                "id": 23, 
                "name": "Parent name", 
                "level": 1
            }, 
            "level": 2
        }, 
        "level": 3
    }, 
    "subcategory": {
        "course_name": "Category Name 3", 
        "title": "Category Title", 
    }
}
]
```

I am trying to read this json and write it in the app such that the structure in the page looks like the following

```
Parent name
    Parent Category 1
        Category 1
            Category Name 1, Category Title
            Category name 2, Category Title
    Parent Category 2
        Category 1
            Category Name 3, Category Title
```

How can i get this structure in angular? Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UXbHvLQelUChIW0GaUm?p=preview) of what i tried.

Comment: You get it by coding. :D

Comment: Am sorry but i am new to angular, and other front end applications. Just started learning those. A little help will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "structure in the page"? I think what you are looking for is parsing JSON using Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: you gotta at least try...

Comment: i am writing a plunkr of what a i tried. I will update it now. Sorry i didnt post a proper question

Comment: i have updated a plunker. Please let me know what i can add to get the structure i was mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to summarize the data first. Then, you can repeat over the summaries to render parent level lists.  Nested repeats can then conditionally display the children data.

The summary arrays (generated with a simple loop, or maybe a fancy library like [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq)) might look like this:

```
$scope.parents = [{
  "id": 23,
  "name": "Parent name",
  "level": 1
}]

$scope.parentCategories = [{
  "id": 38,
  "name": "Parent Category 1"
}, {
  "id": 39,
  "name": "Parent Category 2"
}]

$scope.categories = [{
  "id": 40,
  "name": "Category 1"
}]
```

Then you could use them like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
  <ul>
    <li>{{parent.name}}
      <ul ng-repeat="parentcategory in parentCategories">
        <li>{{parentcategory.name}}
          <ul ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <li>{{category.name}}
              <ul ng-repeat="program in programs" 
                  ng-show="program.category.id == category.id">
                <li ng-show="program.category.parent.id == parentcategory.id">
                  {{program.subcategory.course_name}} {{program.subcategory.title}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to try the code, [here it is on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4Cd7jWzSlVXZ7xMVBqy?p=preview).

Comment: hi.. a small issue i am facing in this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817829/angularjs-passing-parameter-values-in-ng-click-function