# Extracting a value from inside a django loop

Tags: django, angularjs, django-templates

I have a django app where i am using the following in the templates:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
            {% if node.is_leaf_node %}
                <span ng-bind="progid = {{node.program_id}}"></span> 
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

The values of the node will be gone once the recursion takes place. I would like to know how to extract a values outside this loop in the template such that it can be used in another template?

I tried something like this:

```
<span ng-bind="progid = {{node.program_id}}"></span>
```

But when i refer it outside the loop, it does not work!

UPDATE:

as you can see, i am trying to use the value of progid outside the loop.

Comment: Show all relevant code. How are we supposed to know we it is undefined "outside the loop" when we don't know how/where/what you are trying to access ?

Comment: You should probably be passing that value through from the view. Django has the `with` tag to set new template variables, but how are you going to decide which iteration of the loop, and thus which value, you want?  Probably you should loop over `nodes` again in the other template too

Comment: @ExpertSystem i updated the question as you asked :)

Comment: @Anentropic: Actually i am filtering the template according to the view. Thus my node.program_id is always the same value in the tree.

Comment: @crozzfire yes, but isn't it different for each node?

Comment: @Anentropic no because i am already filtering it by the value of program_id at the view.

Comment: @crozzfire if you only ever have a single node then you don't really need to use the `recursetree` tag. And you should be able to access the value you need outside the loop by `{{ nodes.0.program_id }}`

Comment: @Anentropic : i actually need the recursion because, even though the tree is filtered, it has many subtrees in it with the same program id. Basically i am filtering nodes that have the same prog_id

Comment: if you have filtered on `program_id` in the view the natural thing to do would be to pass `program_id` from the view into the template context

Comment: oops...you are right...it worked...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write a custom template tag for this. See the docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Assuming your assignment tag is named `assign`, you would then do

```
{% recursetree nodes %}

    {% assign_node node %}

{% endrecursetree %}
```

And then use the `my_node`

```
{{ my_node.program_id }}
```

Your template tag code should be getting the context. The main context is always the context.dicts[0].

---

Your template tags module (named `bar_tags`):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_dummy_nodes(context, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Just get some dummy objects to work with.
    """
    class Node(object):
        name = None
        def __init__(self, program_id):
            self.program_id = program_id

    nodes = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        nodes.append(Node(i))

    return nodes

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def assign_node(context, node, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Puts your variable into the main context under name ``my_node``.
    """
    context.dicts[0]['my_node'] = node
    return ''
```

---

Your template:

```
<html>
<body>
{% load bar_tags %}

{% get_dummy_nodes as nodes %}

{% for node in nodes %}
    {% assign_node node %}
{% endfor %}

my_node {{ my_node.program_id }}

</body>
</html>
```

---

Note: you should better be doing such things in a view.